# R Error: could not find function is_empty

Tags: r, is-empty

I have tried to run an old script (R 3.4?) with R 4.0...
but it doesn't work.

```
is_empty(c(1,1,2,3))
Error in is_empty(c(1, 1, 2, 3)) : 
could not find function is_empty
```

but `?is_empty` still work. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you reinstalled your old packages? R 4.0 Requires the reinstallation of packages that were build on R 3.x.

Comment: is_empty come from the base, no ? `is_empty {rlang}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify `is_empty` from the `rlang` package. It is only *used by* the `purrr` package - if you read the documentation of `?purrr::is_empty()`, you will see `is_empty` is among list of objects used by `purrr` that are "exported from other packages."

[image]

Here, it clearly tells you it's imported from `rlang`.

So no need to install `purrr` if you dont need/want to - calling either package works:

```
purrr::is_empty(NULL)
# [1] TRUE

rlang::is_empty(NULL)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The `is_empty()` function is in the [`purrr` package](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/) for R version 3.6.3. So you have to include the `purrr` package in your project. To install the `purrr` package, do the following:

```
install.packages ("purrr")
```

And use it in each of your projects by:

```
library ("purrr")
```

Answer (score -1):

Update - purrr no longer has is.empty
And to answer original question, I ran into the same issue, and it was because I was using rapport in my code. Back when it was version 0.51 it had is.empty(), but they got rid of it in version 1.0 and now 1.1.
I did fine the insight package version 0.19.7 seems to work by using the is_empty_object() function. Which does the same thing as the is.empty function.

install.packages("insight")

library(insight)

Comment: This isn't correct - the question is about the function `is_empty()`, which certainly still works (try `purrr::is_empty(NULL)` or `rlang::is_empty(NULL)` not the function `is.empty()`, which is from the `rapport` package